# DomCrawler select only paragraphs

Tags: php, symfony, goutte, domcrawler

I want to extract just the paragraphs in each `.pertanyaan` class, before the `.listjawaban` class using DomCrawler/Goutte Symfony component

Is there any way to do this?
I'm coming with `$crawler->filter('.pertanyaan p')->eq($i)->html()` but it just gives me the first paragraph, because `$i` is the n-th position of `.pertanyaan` class.

```html
<div class="pertanyaan"><p></p>
<p>Karena mengalami mutasi, kromosom mengalami perubahan seperti pada gambar di bawah.</p>
<p><img src="http://indocademy.com/images/ipa_2013_133/53_1.png" alt=""><br>Jenis mutasi tersebut adalah ....</p>
<p></p>
<div class="listjawaban">
<div class="radiojawaban">
    <input type="radio" name="answer_dup_758" id="answer_dup_758_A" value="A" style="display:none" disabled=""><input type="radio" name="answer_758" id="answer_758_A" value="A" onclick="showbutton(758);">A. 
</div>
<div class="pilihanjawaban">
    adisi
</div>
</div>
<div class="listjawaban">
<div class="radiojawaban">
    <input type="radio" name="answer_dup_758" id="answer_dup_758_B" value="B" style="display:none" disabled=""><input type="radio" name="answer_758" id="answer_758_B" value="B" onclick="showbutton(758);">B. 
</div>
<div class="pilihanjawaban">
    delesi
</div>
</div>
<div class="listjawaban">
<div class="radiojawaban">
    <input type="radio" name="answer_dup_758" id="answer_dup_758_C" value="C" style="display:none" disabled=""><input type="radio" name="answer_758" id="answer_758_C" value="C" onclick="showbutton(758);">C. 
</div>
<div class="pilihanjawaban">
    inversi
</div>
</div>
<div class="listjawaban">
<div class="radiojawaban">
    <input type="radio" name="answer_dup_758" id="answer_dup_758_D" value="D" style="display:none" disabled=""><input type="radio" name="answer_758" id="answer_758_D" value="D" onclick="showbutton(758);">D. 
</div>
<div class="pilihanjawaban">
    duplikasi
</div>
</div>
<div class="listjawaban">
<div class="radiojawaban">
    <input type="radio" name="answer_dup_758" id="answer_dup_758_E" value="E" style="display:none" disabled=""><input type="radio" name="answer_758" id="answer_758_E" value="E" onclick="showbutton(758);">E. 
</div>
<div class="pilihanjawaban">
    translokasi
</div>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
<input type="button" class="tombol_jawab" id="tombol_jawab_758" value="Jawab" style="display:none" onclick="executejawaban(758,&quot;http://indocademy.com&quot;)"><input type="button" class="tombol_clear" id="tombol_clear_758" value="Hapus" style="display:none" onclick="clearjawaban(758)">
</div>

<div class="kunci" id="kunci_758" style="display: none">
<div class="tulisanjawab abu">
<input type="button" id="tombol_kunci" value="+" class="jawaban_758" onclick="showkunci(this)">
Jawaban : <img id="loading_758" src="http://indocademy.com/images/loading.gif" style="height:12px;vertical-align:middle">
<span id="hasil_758"> </span>
</div>
<div class="konten_kunci">
<div class="konten_jawaban_758" id="isi_jawaban"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the url I want to crawl: http://indocademy.com/soal/sbmptn/biologi/2013
Everything goes fine except when crawling but at number #53 since there are three paragraph tags to extract (I only assumed each number has its first paragraph tag being the question, and I don't know how to extract all the paragraphs before `.listjawaban` class)

Please help

Comment: What a mess! Please, format code in a reasonable way.

Answer (score 1):

Since the page at the URL doesn't have the structure and the class .pertanyaan does not exist, I copied the HTML snippet into a script and used the DomCrawler to get the four

elements.

```
#!/usr/bin/php

<?php

require ('vendor/autoload.php');

use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

$html = <<<'HTML'
<div class="pertanyaan">
    <p></p>
    <p>Karena mengalami mutasi, kromosom mengalami perubahan seperti pada gambar di bawah.</p>
    <p><img src="http://indocademy.com/images/ipa_2013_133/53_1.png" alt=""><br>Jenis mutasi tersebut adalah ....</p>
    <p></p>
    <div class="listjawaban">
        <div class="radiojawaban">
            <input type="radio" name="answer_dup_758" id="answer_dup_758_A" value="A" style="display:none" disabled="">
            <input type="radio" name="answer_758" id="answer_758_A" value="A" onclick="showbutton(758);">A.
        </div>
        <div class="pilihanjawaban">
            adisi
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="listjawaban">
        <div class="radiojawaban">
            <input type="radio" name="answer_dup_758" id="answer_dup_758_B" value="B" style="display:none" disabled="">
            <input type="radio" name="answer_758" id="answer_758_B" value="B" onclick="showbutton(758);">B.
        </div>
        <div class="pilihanjawaban">
            delesi
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="listjawaban">
        <div class="radiojawaban">
            <input type="radio" name="answer_dup_758" id="answer_dup_758_C" value="C" style="display:none" disabled="">
            <input type="radio" name="answer_758" id="answer_758_C" value="C" onclick="showbutton(758);">C.
        </div>
        <div class="pilihanjawaban">
            inversi
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="listjawaban">
        <div class="radiojawaban">
            <input type="radio" name="answer_dup_758" id="answer_dup_758_D" value="D" style="display:none" disabled="">
            <input type="radio" name="answer_758" id="answer_758_D" value="D" onclick="showbutton(758);">D.
        </div>
        <div class="pilihanjawaban">
            duplikasi
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="listjawaban">
        <div class="radiojawaban">
            <input type="radio" name="answer_dup_758" id="answer_dup_758_E" value="E" style="display:none" disabled="">
            <input type="radio" name="answer_758" id="answer_758_E" value="E" onclick="showbutton(758);">E.
        </div>
        <div class="pilihanjawaban">
            translokasi
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <input type="button" class="tombol_jawab" id="tombol_jawab_758" value="Jawab" style="display:none" onclick="executejawaban(758,&quot;http://indocademy.com&quot;)"><input type="button" class="tombol_clear" id="tombol_clear_758" value="Hapus" style="display:none"
          onclick="clearjawaban(758)">
    </div>

    <div class="kunci" id="kunci_758" style="display: none">
        <div class="tulisanjawab abu">
            <input type="button" id="tombol_kunci" value="+" class="jawaban_758" onclick="showkunci(this)"> Jawaban : <img id="loading_758" src="http://indocademy.com/images/loading.gif" style="height:12px;vertical-align:middle">
            <span id="hasil_758"> </span>
        </div>
        <div class="konten_kunci">
            <div class="konten_jawaban_758" id="isi_jawaban"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
HTML;

$crawler = new Crawler($html);

$output = $crawler->filter('.pertanyaan p')->each(function ($node) {
    return $node->html();
});

print_r($output);
```

The function `each()` returns an array of the four paragraphs.  The resulting array is here:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>
    [1] => Karena mengalami mutasi, kromosom mengalami perubahan seperti pada gambar di bawah.
    [2] => <img src="http://indocademy.com/images/ipa_2013_133/53_1.png" alt=""><br>Jenis mutasi tersebut adalah ....
    [3] =>
)
```